# Please help me withdraw from this contract

Tags: contract-invocation

i only have a check goals reached and safe withdrawal neither work. What is going on!? Been trying to get help forever...

```
contract address: 0x999d5f024439A0EcfD554753e9E4A9eDa9261B73
```

JSON:

```
[ { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "checkGoalReached", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "deadline", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "1496312040" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "beneficiary", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address", "value": "0x64c0118a896bb075448a7f0cd6e760a41cff800c" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "tokenReward", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address", "value": "0x64c0118a896bb075448a7f0cd6e760a41cff800c" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "fundingGoal", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "1e+22" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "amountRaised", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "200000000000000000" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "price", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "1e+21" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "safeWithdrawal", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "name": "ifSuccessfulSendTo", "type": "address", "index": 0, "typeShort": "address", "bits": "", "displayName": "if Successful Send To", "template": "elements_input_address" }, { "name": "fundingGoalInEthers", "type": "uint256", "index": 1, "typeShort": "uint", "bits": "256", "displayName": "funding Goal In Ethers", "template": "elements_input_uint" }, { "name": "durationInMinutes", "type": "uint256", "index": 2, "typeShort": "uint", "bits": "256", "displayName": "duration In Minutes", "template": "elements_input_uint" }, { "name": "etherCostOfEachToken", "type": "uint256", "index": 3, "typeShort": "uint", "bits": "256", "displayName": "ether Cost Of Each Token", "template": "elements_input_uint" }, { "name": "addressOfTokenUsedAsReward", "type": "address", "index": 4, "typeShort": "address", "bits": "", "displayName": "address Of Token Used As Reward", "template": "elements_input_address" } ], "payable": false, "type": "constructor" }, { "payable": true, "type": "fallback" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "name": "beneficiary", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amountRaised", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "GoalReached", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "name": "backer", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "isContribution", "type": "bool" } ], "name": "FundTransfer", "type": "event" } ]
```

Comment: Repeating the same question will not make it easier to solve.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Please do not spam and repeatedly ask the same question. Thanks

Comment: I have not got my question answered my eth is just trapped in a contract that i copied from your websites tutorial for a crowd fund! It is over and all the funds should have been returned but all the ether is trapped in the contract....

Comment: Please edit your existing (non-duplicate) question clearly and make sure to put an accurate title on it. Thanks